# How to insert into the middle of a ListView box

Tags: excel, vba, listview

I have an application which uses a ListView control, and I need to enable a new item to be inserted in the middle of the list, rather than just being tagged onto the end. This is because the list needs to preserve date order. At the moment, all I can manage to do is to add an item to the end of the list, but I suspect there must be a way of inserting a new item rather than deleting all the existing items and re-loading the new updated list. I’d be very grateful for any help with this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
YourListView.ListItems.Add 1, "key", "text"
```

where 1 is the position where you want to add the item.

Comment: Cool, glad to help!